# How do I let the user watch one video in Android app, then return to another activity

Tags: android

If somebody could point me in the right direction, that would be awesome. I'm trying to develop an app for children that will let the user search for and watch one video, and when the video is finished, it will change to another activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play video from youtube - you may use `com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer` in child of `YouTubeBaseActivity`.
It have `setPlayerStateChangeListener` which will solve your problem

```
youTubePlayerView.initialize(GOOGLE_API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                youTubePlayer.cueVideo(videoId);
                youTubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onVideoEnded() {
                        setResult(RESULT_OK);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Where `videoId` is your youtube video id.
Also you would need a `YouTubePlayerView` widget for this.